# Spring autowiring a wrapped HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Consider a Spring-based webapplication, running in Tomcat.

We created an ordinary Java EE Filter, which is casting the `ServletRequest` into a `HttpServletRequest` and wrapping it into an `AppHttpServletRequest` which extends `HttpServletRequestWrapper`.

```
public class AppRequestFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Filter start");
        AppHttpServletRequest appHttpServletRequest = new AppHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest)request);
        chain.doFilter(appHttpServletRequest, response);
        System.out.println("Filter end");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Then `@Autowired` this into a Spring `@Component`

```
@Autowired(required = false) private transient AppHttpServletRequest appRequest;
@Autowired(required = false) private transient HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
```

The results are very surprising:

1. Sometimes, it is working as intended: the `appRequest` is autowired and `httpRequest`remains null
2. Sometimes, it is NOT working as intended: the `appRequest` is null and the `httpRequest` is autowired instead; and the filter has been run through...

Does somebody has an idea WHY this behavior is changing randomly?

It seems to happen right after a deploy of the app to Tomcat. Stopping an starting the app again fixes the issue then. Very weird!

Comment: Nothing happens randomly. Explain under what condition _exactly_ you get those behaviors.

Comment: Do you have an applicaitonContext.xml file declaring beans?
Please post that as well.

Comment: Where do you inject the requests. If you inject something with small scope(request) in something with big scope(like singleton Controller) - bad things will happen. Take a look at Aop Scoped Proxy

Comment: I would consider injecting a `HttpServletRequest` as a bad practice in your components. Your components should, in general, not be aware of the environment they run in. Your web layer should prepare everything so that your down stream components don't have to do anything with the request anymore. What if you want/need to reuse the same component for JMS or SOAP based webservices?